# Google Charts - Show day of the week in local language

Tags: charts, localization, google-visualization, weekday

How do I make a Google Chart axis to use day of the week names in different languages (e.g. in German).

For tooltip I use

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'EEEE, dd.MM.YYYY' });
```

Here it produces `Tuesday, 31.03.2020`, and I would like to see `Dienstag, 31.03.2020`

For axis I use option

```
hAxis: { format: "EE, dd/MM" }
```

This produces `Tu, 31/03`, and I would like to see `Di, 31/03`

What is the way to do it please?

Comment: I think you should look at http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime around DateTimePatternGenerator, as https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat say they use that ICU format...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately Formatter DateFormat does only support formatType, pattern and timeZone options, there is no possibility to change locale or use locale of browser settings.  ICU would be capable of doing it, but I don't know how to apply it in Google visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the language option when loading google charts...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  language: 'de'
});
```